# Positioning a new view within Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt

I have successfully created a new view, passing in the primary ID from my plugin.xml and a unique secondary ID. All is well. It pops up as one would want.

However ... it pops up in completely the wrong folder.

I want it to go along side the other one's that are of the same type. It is the main folder center panel I want it created in. Now I can manually move it (as a user) and put it where I want it.

Feel so close to this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  When laying out the folders in the perspectiveExtensions extended class, I need to tell it where additional views will end up.  You do this by calling the IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder() passing in the necessary wildcards where necessary.

```
bodyleft.addPlaceholder( "MyViewId:*" );
```

This works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear by "wrong folder"? 
Two things here. 
First, if it's showing up in the wrong place in the workbench, then you need to use `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension to place it in the right place in the perspective.
Second, if it's not grouping with set of views, then you need to add "category" in the view extension to show up in the right category in "Show View".
Hope these two points will help you out. Please let me know if I completely missed your point.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I went a slightly different route.

Comment: Plz add your feedback if you it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a perspective extension and use the ["relative" attribute of the view definition](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html#e.view) there.